# How to add timer after sweetalert2 open?

Tags: javascript, alert, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to add timer after callback another function in [Sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).
In the example just add timer when `swal` run.

this is basic code :

```
swal({
  title: 'alert!',
  text: 'I need this close after my function',
})
```

and below is `ajax` and I need the `swal` close in `second` after `ajax` success

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {some: data},
    success: function (json) {
        if (json.status === 'OK') {
            swal({
                timer:2000
            });
        }
    }
});
```

but when `ajax` success, new modal of `swal()` opened with timer, not close the current `swal()`

Comment: provide lines of code you have written

Comment: I have completed with code

Comment: ofcourse, it will open a new modal since you are using swal() function again

Comment: any idea for it ?

Comment: updated my answer. Check if this works for you

Comment: thanks :) its help me a lot, I edited your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is inpired by answer From Gaurav Chaudhary. Id modified with standard of swal doc. I publish this because he not accept my edit.

```js
//if(swal.isVisible()) { // uncomment to check if modal swal visible
    setTimeout(function(){
        swal.closeModal();
     }, 2000);
//}


swal('Any fool can use a computer')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide current modal on ajax success. Try this

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: url,
type: "GET",
data: {some: data},
success: function (json) {
    if (json.status === 'OK') {
        hideSwal()
    }
}});
function hideSwal(){
setTimeout(function(){
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('swal2-confirm')[0]
  button.click()
},2000)
}
```

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('swal2-confirm')[0]
  button.click()
},2000)
swal('Any fool can use a computer')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,
bu I need after some `function` with ajax and success, the `swal()` closed by timer ..